# Rails: Rails_best_practices - command not found when run on a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this line of code:

```
output = `rails_best_practices /home/jordi/src/adventureManager/app`
```

When I run that in irb, or inside any .rb and I call that .rb from ruby output get some content.

But when I call it inside my model output gets an empty string.

Instead other commands like

```
output = `cat /home/jordi/src/adventureManager/app/*`
```

will work everywhere, including inside models
I am pretty clueless about this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's `rails_best_practices`? is it in your path? My guess is that you got a command not found to stderr when you ran it inside the model.

Comment: you are right. The problem is rails_best_practices is a gem, I have it globally installed but I dont have it in my Gemfile for that rails project. This is very inconvenient as commands I am running can be configured after deployment. So any time someone can come with a command that is not included in the Gemfile and the app will break, any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: You should really include your gem file as a part of your project so that everyone working on your project uses the same gem file

Answer (score 1):

Or you might try using something like the following from your app root:

```
output = `bundle exec rails_best_practices /home/jordi/src/adventureManager/app`
```

Good luck!

Comment: the problem came to be that I have rails_best_practices installed as a gem in the system but it is not in the gemfile, when I added to the gemfile it worked as expected. But I would really want it to work without needig to specify anything in the gemfile

Answer (score 0):

I had this same concern when working on a **Rails 6** application.

After adding the [rails_best_practices](https://github.com/flyerhzm/rails_best_practices) gem to my `Gemfile`:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rails_best_practices', '~> 1.20'
end
```

I ran the command below to install it in my application:

```
bundle install
```

However, when I ran the command `rails_best_practices .`, I get the error below:

```
rails_best_practices: command not found
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that the **path** of the **rails_best_practices** executable was not yet available in my current **shell/terminal**.

I simply closed the current **shell/terminal** I was on and re-opened a new one.

This time when I ran `rails_best_practices .`, it worked fine.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**